# Adobe Air Debugger lagging my League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

I have two LoL icons on my task bar one is titled Adobe Air Debugger and the other is my LoL client.  I am having random bouts of lag that have nothing to do with my connection of FPS.  I did just install a new graphics card with the most recent display adapter.  Has anyone experienced this before and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would update Adobe air at WWW.Adobe.com and run a graphic card driver update search on the website of the kind of card you got its much more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Air Debugger is the program that League of Legends runs through, it IS League of Legends. The lag is server side on the game more often than not.